# Add arrows to thumbnails of jssor slider

Tags: jssor

I have a basic Jssor Slider with thumbnails vertical on the left side and images on the right. I would like to add arrows to be able to scroll the thumbnails up and down. Can you please let me know what code I should add and where? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var options = {
            $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
            $Idle: 4000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
            $SlideDuration: 500,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
            $DragOrientation: 3,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $Cols is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)
            $UISearchMode: 0,                                   //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).

            $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,              //[Required] Class to create thumbnail navigator instance
                $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always

                $Loop: 1,                                       //[Optional] Enable loop(circular) of carousel or not, 0: stop, 1: loop, 2 rewind, default value is 1
                $SpacingX: 3,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each thumbnail in pixel, default value is 0
                $SpacingY: 3,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each thumbnail in pixel, default value is 0
                $Cols: 6,                              //[Optional] Number of pieces to display, default value is 1
                $Align: 253,                          //[Optional] The offset position to park thumbnail,

                $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                    $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                    $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                    $Steps: 6                                       //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
                }
            }
        };

        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

        //responsive code begin
        //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizing
        function ScaleSlider() {
            var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
            if (parentWidth)
                jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(parentWidth, 720));
            else
                window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
        }
        ScaleSlider();

        $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
        $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
        $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
        //responsive code end
    });
</script>
<!-- Jssor Slider Begin -->
<!-- To move inline styles to css file/block, please specify a class name for each element. --> 
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; width: 720px;
    height: 480px; overflow: hidden;">

    <!-- Loading Screen -->
    <div u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
        <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity:0.7; position: absolute; display: block;
            background-color: #000; top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
        </div>
        <div style="position: absolute; display: block; background: url(../img/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;
            top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Slides Container -->
    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 720px; height: 480px;
        overflow: hidden;">
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="../img/travel/01.jpg" />
            <img u="thumb" src="../img/travel/thumb-01.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="../img/travel/02.jpg" />
            <img u="thumb" src="../img/travel/thumb-02.jpg" />
        </div>
        <!--<div>
            <img u="image" src="../img/travel/03.jpg" />
            <img u="thumb" src="../img/travel/thumb-03.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="../img/travel/04.jpg" />
            <img u="thumb" src="../img/travel/thumb-04.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="../img/travel/05.jpg" />
            <img u="thumb" src="../img/travel/thumb-05.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="../img/travel/06.jpg" />
            <img u="thumb" src="../img/travel/thumb-06.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="../img/travel/07.jpg" />
            <img u="thumb" src="../img/travel/thumb-07.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="../img/travel/08.jpg" />
            <img u="thumb" src="../img/travel/thumb-08.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="../img/travel/09.jpg" />
            <img u="thumb" src="../img/travel/thumb-09.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="../img/travel/10.jpg" />
            <img u="thumb" src="../img/travel/thumb-10.jpg" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <img u="image" src="../img/travel/11.jpg" />
            <img u="thumb" src="../img/travel/thumb-11.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="../img/travel/12.jpg" />
            <img u="thumb" src="../img/travel/thumb-12.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="../img/travel/13.jpg" />
            <img u="thumb" src="../img/travel/thumb-13.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="../img/travel/14.jpg" />
            <img u="thumb" src="../img/travel/thumb-14.jpg" />
        </div>-->
    </div>
    <!--#region Thumbnail Navigator Skin Begin -->
    <!-- Help: http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-thumbnail-navigator-jquery.html -->
    <style>
        /* jssor slider thumbnail navigator skin 07 css */
        /*
        .jssort07 .p            (normal)
        .jssort07 .p:hover      (normal mouseover)
        .jssort07 .pav          (active)
        .jssort07 .pav:hover    (active mouseover)
        .jssort07 .pdn          (mousedown)
        */
        .jssort07 {
            position: absolute;
            /* size of thumbnail navigator container */
            width: 800px;
            height: 100px;
        }

            .jssort07 .p {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 99px;
                height: 66px;
            }

            .jssort07 .i {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                width: 99px;
                height: 66px;
                filter: alpha(opacity=80);
                opacity: .8;
            }

            .jssort07 .p:hover .i, .jssort07 .pav .i {
                filter: alpha(opacity=100);
                opacity: 1;
            }

            .jssort07 .o {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                width: 97px;
                height: 64px;
                border: 1px solid #000;
                box-sizing: content-box;
                transition: border-color .6s;
                -moz-transition: border-color .6s;
                -webkit-transition: border-color .6s;
                -o-transition: border-color .6s;
            }

            .jssort07 .pav .o {
                border-color: #0099ff;
            }

            .jssort07 .p:hover .o {
                border-color: #fff;
                transition: none;
                -moz-transition: none;
                -webkit-transition: none;
                -o-transition: none;
            }

            .jssort07 .p.pdn .o {
                border-color: #0099ff;
            }

            * html .jssort07 .o {
                /* ie quirks mode adjust */
                width /**/: 99px;
                height /**/: 66px;
            }
    </style>
    <!-- thumbnail navigator container -->
    <div u="thumbnavigator" class="jssort07" style="width: 720px; height: 100px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
        <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin Begin -->
        <div u="slides" style="cursor: default;">
            <div u="prototype" class="p">
                <div u="thumbnailtemplate" class="i"></div>
                <div class="o"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin End -->
        <!--#region Arrow Navigator Skin Begin -->
        <!-- Help: http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-arrow-navigator-jquery.html -->
        <style>
            /* jssor slider arrow navigator skin 11 css */
            /*
            .jssora11l                  (normal)
            .jssora11r                  (normal)
            .jssora11l:hover            (normal mouseover)
            .jssora11r:hover            (normal mouseover)
            .jssora11l.jssora11ldn      (mousedown)
            .jssora11r.jssora11rdn      (mousedown)
            */
            .jssora11l, .jssora11r {
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                /* size of arrow element */
                width: 37px;
                height: 37px;
                cursor: pointer;
                background: url(../img/a11.png) no-repeat;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            .jssora11l {
                background-position: -11px -41px;
            }

            .jssora11r {
                background-position: -71px -41px;
            }

            .jssora11l:hover {
                background-position: -131px -41px;
            }

            .jssora11r:hover {
                background-position: -191px -41px;
            }

            .jssora11l.jssora11ldn {
                background-position: -251px -41px;
            }

            .jssora11r.jssora11rdn {
                background-position: -311px -41px;
            }
        </style>
        <!-- Arrow Left -->
        <span u="arrowleft" class="jssora11l" style="top: 123px; left: 8px;">
        </span>
        <!-- Arrow Right -->
        <span u="arrowright" class="jssora11r" style="top: 123px; right: 8px;">
        </span>
        <!--#endregion Arrow Navigator Skin End -->
    </div>
    <!--#endregion Thumbnail Navigator Skin End -->
    <!-- Trigger -->
</div>
<!-- Jssor Slider End -->
```

[jssor slider thumbnail with arrows](http://www.jssor.com/testcase/thumbnail-navigator-with-arrows.source.html)

[jssor slider with 4 arrows](http://www.jssor.com/testcase/slider-with-4-arrows.source.html)